# How to get the column index of the current cell?

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, epplus

I have this code here...

```
For Each cell In worksheet.Cells(8, 2, lastRow, lastCol)
    Select Case "What Goes Here"
    End Select
Next
```

I want to verify the column that the current cell is in. I can use...

```
cell.Address
```

but that returns a string with both the column letter and row. Would there be another way of getting maybe just the index or letter only of the column or would I just have to do something like....

```
If cell.Address.Contains("A")
```

Answer (score 20):

You get it via `cell.Start.Column`:

```
int colIndex = cell.Start.Column;
```

`Start` is always the same as `End` when you use `foreach`.

The same if you want the row-number instead:

```
int rowNum = cell.Start.Row;
```

Note that the column- and rows are not zero based indices but 1-based. So the first column of the first row has `Row=1` and `Column=1`.